# How to get better Polymorphic Type Inference in Haskell for this example?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-inference

I have the following data type:

```
data PValue = IV Int | BV Bool | SV String
            deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I want to write a function that generates PValue from an Int, a Bool or a String like:

```
> loadVal 3
IV 3

> loadVal True
BV Bool

> loadVal "Ha"
SV "Ha"
```

Since the argument to loadVal is polymorphic, I tried to create a class:

```
class PValues v where
  loadVal :: v -> PValue

instance PValues Int where
  loadVal v = IV v

instance PValues Bool where
  loadVal v = BV v

instance PValues String where
  loadVal s = SV s
```

This appears to work, except for Int:

```
> loadVal "Abc"
SV "Abc"
> loadVal False
BV False
> loadVal 3

<interactive>:8:1:
    No instance for (PValues v0) arising from a use of `loadVal'
    The type variable `v0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance PValues String -- Defined at Types.hs:22:10
      instance PValues Bool -- Defined at Types.hs:19:10
      instance PValues Int -- Defined at Types.hs:16:10
    In the expression: loadVal 3
    In an equation for `it': it = loadVal 3

<interactive>:8:9:
    No instance for (Num v0) arising from the literal `3'
    The type variable `v0' is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus 8 others
    In the first argument of `loadVal', namely `3'
    In the expression: loadVal 3
    In an equation for `it': it = loadVal 3
```

I understand that this is because `3` by itself is of ambiguous type (could be `Int`, `Float`, etc). Is there a way to force this type inference without explicitly annotating it in the call site?

Comment: Can you try making `instance PValues Integer where loadVal v = IV (fromInteger v)`? You may then find that default defaulting to Integer gets you there.

Comment: @AndrewC That may not work as `fromInteger` expects `Integer`.

Comment: @Sibi Oops - typo corrected - I meant Integer!

Comment: @AndrewC That's a nice workaround and it indeed works. You should post that as an answer. :)

Comment: Alternatively using `instance PValues Int where loadVal v = IV (fromIntegral v)` also works.

Comment: However, I want to be able to using Data.Text.Text instead of String in PValue. How do we get the type inference to work, without expecting type annotations at call site?

Comment: @donatello You mean you want to replace `data PValue = IV Int | BV Bool | SV String` with `data PValue = IV Int | BV Bool | SV Text`, or with `data PValue = IV Int | BV Bool | SV String | TV Text`?

Comment: Yes, I just want `SV Text` not an extra `TV Text`.

Comment: I am writing a library, and I don't want the user to have to annotate each string as `Text` while calling `loadVal`. I expect the user to use `-XOverloadedStrings` and let the type inference read the parameter as a `Text`. I hope I am clear. Is this possible to do?

Comment: `instance PValues String where loadVal s = SV (fromString s)`?

Comment: I want the definition for `instance PValues Text where loadVal s = ?` as I want the input to be read as Text directly. The caller of `loadVal` will probably use it as `loadVal "abc"` and I want this to load a Text type for PValue.

Comment: @Sibi I'm happy for anyone (definitely including you) to write that up - I should really be filing an exciting stationery order! I promise an upvote for the willing volunteer, especially if they @ reply me to let me know it's done.

Comment: @donatello Are you having problems with `instance PValues Text where loadVal s = SV s` against `data PValue = IV Int | BV Bool | SV Text`?

Comment: Yes, `loadVal "abc"` does not run even with `-XOverloadedStrings` as "abc" is ambiguous - it is of type `IsString s`, and that could be a Bytestring, Text, String, whatever. Anyway out of this without type annotations?

Comment: Ah. Defaulting applies to Num instances. Hmmm.

Comment: ... There's a proposal in Haskell Prime to be able to do it for arbitrary types, but it's just a proposal at this stage.

Comment: @donatello If you major motivation is to not to make the user of your library not to annotate `Text` at call site, then you can define instances for both `String` and `Text`. For the `String` instance use the `pack` function to ultimately convert it to `Text`.

Comment: @donatello Oh - I think more recent versions of GHC allow default declarations for the `IsString` typeclass, so you could try adding `default (String)` or `default (Text)` to your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding @AndrewC's comment here. For making `loadVal 3` work, do the
type conversion while instantiating:

```
instance PValues Integer where
  loadVal v = IV (fromInteger v)
```

Now, if you want to make it work with `Text` type and don't want your
user to explicitly annotate it, give both the instances for `String`
as well as `Text`:

```
data PValue = IV Int | BV Bool | SV Text
            deriving (Show, Eq)

instance PValues String where
  loadVal s = SV (pack s)

instance PValues Text where
  loadVal s = SV s
```

For places, where the compiler is able to infer that your input is
`Text` data type, it will not have to go through the `pack` overhead.